# Logging frameworks and synchronization in multi-threaded apps

Tags: multithreading, logging

I want to use a logging framework like log4cxx in a multi-threaded application.

If the output of the log will be to a file, correct serialization of the messages is needed.
I was asking myself how (and if) these frameworks get correct serialization of the output without using some sort of synchronization object.

I guess that if it is using synchronization objects (for example to access a queue to log messages), this could cause changes in the behaviour of the involved threads, so also changing the behaviour (and bugs...) of the whole logged application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log4cxx is indeed synchronized, like the other log4XXX frameworks. The synchronization is done in the appenders and is necessary to guarantee that content of log entries are not mixed together. This **does not** change the behavior of your threads, but the threads do encounter a small performance hit. The performance hit is small compared to the performance hit of I/O when logging to a file.

If you are still worried about performance you can consider using asynchronous logging (using the [AsyncAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AsyncAppender.html) that handles logging in a separate thread. Using the async approach you cannot be guaranteed that messages are logged (e.g. if the application crashes before the logging thread handles the message). The most simple way to improve performance is to reduce the amount of logging.